# Fancybox not stretching when using to display form

Tags: forms, fancybox, width, inline

I want to display a simple form inside fancybox overlay, which also works nice on smaller screen. i've set up an example on here http://design.imago.ee/test/fancybox-form/index1.html 
Initially i set the form width to be 450px, at 620px screen size im setting the form width to 100% and after i have done it, fancybox window collapses width wise and the form is not displayed properly. Interestingly that doesnt happen with regular text content (second button in the example). I know that i could just change the width manually with media queries, but it isnt really a good solution. Can anyone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very elegant solution but will give you an idea and porbably put you closer to your goal

Change in fancybox css

```
.fancybox-inner {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Script

Calculate width of window and adjust the width of `content`, use `setInterval` so any change in width will be adjusted dynamically.

```
setInterval(dimension, 100);

function dimension() {
    $('.content').css('width', $(window).width() * 0.6);
}
```

Demo

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        padding: 0,
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                locked: false
            },
            title: {
                type: 'inside'
            }
        }
    });

    setInterval(dimension, 100);

    function dimension() {
        $('.content').css('width', $(window).width() * 0.6);
    }

});
```

```css
.fancybox-inner {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/* =========================== Layout styles =================== */
 body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    font: 14px/1.4'Open sans', sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px 4%;
}
.centered-wrap {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
a.fancybox {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: #59a3d3;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 4px 7px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.content {
    padding: 20px 30px;
}
input[type="text"] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 30px;
    font: 13px/30px'Open sans', sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 7px;
}
#form {
    width: 450px;
    padding: 30px;
}
#form .row {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#form .col {
    float: left;
}
#form .col1 {
    width: 25%;
}
#form .col2 {
    width: 75%;
}
#form label {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 6px 10px 0 0;
}
/* ======================= media queries ======================= */
 @media screen and (max-width: 620px) {
    #form {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    #form .col {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        text-align: center;
        margin-right: 10px
    }
    #form label {
    }
}
/* ======================== clearfix =========================== */
/* Force Element To Self-Clear its Children */
 .clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content:" ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
 * html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
.clearfix {
    display: block;
}
/* close commented backslash hack */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<div class="centered-wrap">
    <p><a class="fancybox" href="#form">Fancybox with form</a></p>
    <div style="display: none;">
        <div id="form" class="content">
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col col1">
                    <label>Form label</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col col2">
                    <input type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col col1">
                    <label>Form label</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col col2">
                    <input type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col col1">
                    <label>Form label</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col col2">
                    <input type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nm8v84c8/)

Note: Adjust the fiddle view screen to see how form width adjust itself with the change of screen size.

Comment: Thanks mate, solves the problem. 1 question though, isnt the constant interval gonna slow down the page? I dont know much about js, but it seems like its pretty much constantly running, right?

Comment: no, it will not hurt the website, it's just with form and only execute when form open, I'm even using this on one of eCommerce site, the page has minimum 12 products and each product box adjust it's height dynamically, never feel the page is slow loading or causing any problem and if you like you can increase the delay change `setInterval(dimension, 100);` to this `setInterval(dimension, 500);`

Comment: oh, thats nice. Thanks. Wait, did you use it for product box height? That sounds interesting. Ive been using this script equalize.js but i cant seem to find a way to equalize per row. It just takes the highest from the whole list and adjust everything according to it. Maybe i could learn something from your script?